# Making span not wrap inside other divs with fixed width

Tags: css, html, word-wrap

How do you make the contents of a 100% width span not wrap when the text is more than 100% of parent? I have monkeyed around with `whitespace: nowrap;` with no luck.

**PROBLEM: `span.firstname, span.lastname, span.email` all wrap text when their contents are longer than `div.name, div.personal, or div.account_view`.** I would like the 3 spans to go for however long their content is (no wrap).

*HTML:*

```
<div class="account_view">
  <div class="personal">

    <div class="picture">
      <img src="example.png" />
      <span>Image caption</span>
    </div>

    <div class="name">
      <span class="first">Firstname</span>
      <span class="last">Lastname</span>
      <span class="email">email@email.com</span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
div.account_view {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 700px;
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 0;
}
div.account_view div.personal {
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
div.account_view div.personal div.picture {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
div.account_view div.personal div.picture img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div.account_view div.personal div.picture span {
  display: block;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -27px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  color: #eee;
}
div.account_view div.personal div.name {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: -25px;
}

div.account_view div.personal div.name > * {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 300;
  white-space: normal;
}
div.account_view div.personal div.name span.first {
  font-size: 125px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
div.account_view div.personal div.name span.last {
  position: relative;
  top: -9px;
  left: 5px;
  font-size: 56px;
}
div.account_view div.personal div.name span.email {
  font-size: 29px;
  position: relative;
  left: 8px;
}
```

---

**GOAL: (hover over)**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to float left?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add to the span's CSS
    `white-space: nowrap`

Additionally you can use
    `text-overflow: ellipsis`

to get a nice "..." When the text is cutoff

Comment: This worked but I ended up changing my HTML so that things work better. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Give the span(s) a `display: block` or `display: inline-block` and set `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. The text doesn't seem to not wrap until it gets too big for `div.personal` or `div.account_view`

Comment: Also when you specify a fixed height for the span? (Use the height of one line then)

Comment: Even with `height: 1em;`, the span still wraps at `div.account_view`

Comment: And if you use '1ex' as height? (ex is related to font height, em to font size)